# Whats the role of this && operator in this code?

Tags: javascript

My code is failing here at this part ..i cant understand what is the role of this && operator in js?

```
    export function calculateLineTotals(line, invoice) {

    let totals = _calculateLineTotals(line, invoice)
    return {
    amount: totals.amount && 
        totals.amount.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber(),
    vatRate: totals.vatRate && 
        totals.vatRate.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber(),
    grossAmount: totals.grossAmount && 
        totals.grossAmount.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber(),
    vatAmount: totals.vatAmount && 
        totals.vatAmount.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber(),
    }
```

Comment: Read the JavaScript documentation regarding the [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description).

Comment: "My code is failing here" - can you be more specific about how it's failing? Do you have an error message in your browser console?

Comment: You can read it like: `if totals.amount is truthy`, then I want it to get `totals.amount.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber()` otherwise it will be `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
totals.amount && totals.amount.decimalPlaces(2).toNumber()
```

`totals.amount` will evaluate to the value

`&&` will evaluate the right handside expression if lefthandside evaluates to true (not `null` or `undefined` or `0`)

i guess thats what you want to know

this eliminates possibility of `cant evaluate 'decimalPlaces' of undefined` error

Comment: great exactly ...thats what i wanted to know